# Accuracy of a polygon fitting algorithm

Tags: accuracy, geometry

I have a polygon $P$ which I have to fit with a rectangle $R$, as shown in the figure below. This is done by varying the dimension of the rectangle, and choosing the dimension that best fits the polygon. This is done for a fixed position of the rectangle.. that is, no rotation is done.

Now, we define -

True Positive area (TP) = $P \cap R$

False Positive area (FP) = $R \setminus P$

True Negative area (TN) = $\bar{R} \setminus P$

False Negative area (FN) = $P \setminus R$

In order to find how accurately the rectangle fits the polygon, I want to measure the accuracy, which is simply: (TP + TN)/(TP + FP + TN + FN). In my case, TP, FP and FN are pretty straight forward. I am facing problem measuring the TN, because $\bar{R}$ is actually an infinite region. For motivation: consider an access control scenario, where a user located anywhere outside a building must not get access to online services provided for that building. How can I measure accuracy then? Is binary classification even applicable to this scenario?

A second question for the same scenario: let, my objective function is to minimize (FP + FN). Is it equivalent to maximizing (TP - FP)? If it is, how do I argue on the equivalence?

[image]

Comment: I would bound $\bar{R}$ by the total height and total width of your figure. Then you’re making your comparison to the naïve rectangle, somewhat like using $R^2$ to compare to naïve guessing of the pooled mean every time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different error metric will give you what you want. You can use the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), which is the harmonic mean of precision and recall. Recall is the percentage of the area of the polygon that is contained in the rectangle. Precision is the percentage of area inside the rectangle that is within the polygon.

$F1 = \frac{P * R}{P + R}$